# Passagem de id para outra página Ionic 3 (API RESTful com php)

Tags: php, mysql, typescript, ionic3

Boa tarde, 
Estou fazendo um app em ionic 3 utilizando a API RESTful com php para conexão com o banco MYSQL e meu app lista Cômodos de uma casa com seu respectivo consumo, segue imagens do app atualmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clicar nesse botão Ver Detalhes eu gostaria que o id do cômodo escolhido passe para a outra página, segue os códigos:

**Home.html**

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let comodos of comodo">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="../assets/img/ionic3-ico.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{(comodos.descricao)}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="left">
      <button ion-button color="dark">
          <ion-item class="transparente">
            <ion-icon name="flash" color="primary" item-left></ion-icon>
            <span>{{(comodos.potencia_atual)}} Wh</span>
          </ion-item>
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button color="warning" (click)="doSearch(comodos.id)">
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      Ver Detalhes {{(comodos.id)}}
    </button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

**Home.ts**

```
public doSearch(id_comodo) {
 this.nav.setRoot(TripsPage, {id: this.id});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você fez quase tudo certo, só passou o id errado no setRoot, o certo seria:

```
public doSearch(id_comodo) {
  this.nav.setRoot(TripsPage, {id: id_comodo});
}
```

Comment: é porque esse this.id ta armazenado o id do usuário e eu não sabia como passava o id do comodo, obrigado pela resposta.